# Hide Wordpress dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

I'm new to wordpress and a bit confused with something. I'm trying to build a classified marketplace type of website for myself. I am NOT building this for a "client". I will probably be using a hack of several different plugins as my coding skills are not up to par. Eventually I will hopefully have lots of users who will be composed of buyers & sellers.

My question pertains to the WP dashboard. When buyers/sellers sign up for my site, will they be able to see the backend WP dashboard? I would prefer that they NOT be able to access a backend dashboard at all let alone a WP branded one. Is this possible? If so any clue as to how this might be accomplished?

thank you Brian

Answer (score 2):

Normal users do not actually see the 'backend' WP dashboard. What they are seeing is a 'profile' type page meant for the original functionality of wordpres; being a blog.

If you do not want users to go to this page when they log-in, you can use a couple of hooks. Here is some code that redirects to the front page after logging-in and logging-out. This goes in your functions.php file.

```
add_action('login_form', 'ang_redirect_to_front_page');
add_action('wp_logout', 'go_home');

function ang_redirect_to_front_page() {

    global $redirect_to;
    if (!isset($_GET['redirect_to'])) {
        $redirect_to = get_option('siteurl');
    }
}
function go_home(){
  wp_redirect( home_url() );
  exit();
}
```

And, if your theme is still displaying the menu at the top of the screen that allows the users to go to this 'profile' area, you can go into your footer.php file and remove this:

```
<?php wp_footer();?>
```

However, if you do this, then you will not see it as the admin either.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is might not be the thing to use for that kind of website, even with a bunch of plugins. Read up on other content management systems just incase.

This link might answer your question:
http://buddypress.org/support/topic/how-to-prevent-non-admins-from-accessing-wp-admin-dashboard/

You can also add this to your theme's function.php file:

```
// DISABLE ADMIN BAR FOR ALL USERS
show_admin_bar( false );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too used to wordpress, use WOOCOMMERCE plugin. Its completely free and well documented